# Installing Python 2.7 for all users on SLES 11

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pip, python-module

I installed Python 2.7 on SLES 11 box that previously was running Python 2.6. To do so I used a script [described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371726/135946) and run it as a root user. Everything went well but when it was done I discovered few issues:

1. No symbolic links were created and no path updated so I had to manually update the path to link to the new installation bin directory `/opt/python2.7/bin`
2. Everything runs good until I switch from root to the normal user at which point Python shell runs but some modules I installed such as PyYAML are missing. Again, these are OK when I run Python as root
3. As a regular user I'm not able to run pip, easy_install and wheel. For pip I get `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

P.S. Following @user suggestion I tried adding the following path taken from `sys.path` of the root user to `.bashrc` which did not fix the problem

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/python2.7/lib/python27.zip:/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7:/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2:/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-3.11-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg:/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect-4.2.0-py2.7.egg:/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptyprocess-0.5.1-py2.7.egg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credible / official sources: no reply from [official forum](https://forums.suse.com/showthread.php?1102-Python-2-7-support-for-SLES-11). Apart from the SO-link you mentioned, there is also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7644/how-to-do-a-binary-install-of-python-2-7-on-suse-linux-enterprise-server-11, which sketches the way to do it described in [Installing Python 2.7 on SLES 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940296/installing-python-2-7-on-sles-11/11371726#11371726) (SO is not official, is it? ;-)

Concerning your problem: both 2. and 3. might be caused by elements lacking in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path).

To test this, type

```
import sys; sys.path
```

both in user and root python and check for differences. These need to be merged. Try using [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) first to test this, but be aware that [there are different methods how to adjust `sys.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893598/pythonpath-vs-sys-path).

If you just need to fix this for normal (non-daemon) users, adjusting the system-wide bash profile would be an easy solution.

(Any questions/feedback is welcome... :-)

Comment: Indeed all "eggs" are missing from the regular user sys.path. Thank you for your reply I was afraid that the bounty will go unclaimed :)

Comment: @Bostone: that had happened to one of my bounties once and it was a disappointing feeling :). Did it help you enough, or do you require further help?

Comment: I'm in the process of determining that ;)

Comment: It's crazy that 2.7 is not really supported on SLES 11. Thanks for your help, enjoy the bounty

Comment: @Bostone: You're welcome. Good that it worked out ok. Thanks for the bounty. And for sure, 2.7 should be well-supported, but ...

Comment: Sorry to revisit this but collecting path from root user and putting it into PYTHONPATH nor using sys.path.append fixed the problem. Still when I try `import yaml` I get `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yaml` error

Comment: And no luck running pip or easy_install

Comment: as a Python newbie I'm not sure if I'm setting the PYTHONPATH correctly so I put the whole thing as P.S. into the original question

Comment: @Bostone: PYTHONPATH just needs to contain additional modules. Try again as `export PYTHONPATH=/opt/python2.7/lib/python27.zip...` and post the results if it does not work, together with `sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH` befor and after. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001851/pythonpath-ignored.